# EF Code First One to Many and Reverse One To One Relationship

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I am trying to create one-to-many and reverse one-to-one relationship using code first. Here is what I ma trying to do

1) One-to-Many between two classes and it works as expected.

```
    public class X
    {
        [Key]
        public int XId { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Y> Y { get; set; }

    }

    public class Y
    {
        [Key]
        public int YId { get; set; }
        public int XId { get; set; }
        public X X { get; set; }
    }

    public class DataContext : DbContext
    {
        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Y>()
                .HasRequired(y => y.X)
                .WithMany(x => x.Y)
                .HasForeignKey(y => y.XId);
        }
    }
```

Now what I want to do is to create Reverse One-to-One optional relationship between Y and X, such that the X will contain a foreign key of Y...How is it possible? Here is what I am trying to do and it throws some Multiplicity Error

```
       public class X
        {
            [Key]
            public int XId { get; set; }
            public ICollection<Y> Y { get; set; }
            public int YId {get; set; }
            [ForiegnKey("YId")]
            public Y YOptional { get; set; }
        }

        public class Y
        {
            [Key]
            public int YId { get; set; }
            public int XId { get; set; }
            public X X { get; set; }
            public X XOptional {get; set; }
        }

        public class DataContext : DbContext
        {
            protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
            {
                modelBuilder.Entity<Y>()
                    .HasRequired(y => y.X)
                    .WithMany(x => x.Y)
                    .HasForeignKey(y => y.XId);

                modelBuilder.Entity<X>()
                    .HasOptional(x => x.YOptional)
                    .WithOptionalDependent(y=> y.XOptional);
            }
        }
```

Comment: You want `X` to contain a *collection* of `YId` foreign keys?

Comment: As a side-note, you better mark `X.Y` and `Y.X` as `virtual` properties.

Comment: Yes, but that should be optional.

Comment: I already marked them as virtual in my original code, just to keep things simple, I didn't mark here

Comment: And by the way, X would have corresponding Y..So I think it should have to be one-to-one relationship

Comment: The problem is that `X` has *many* `Y`, I can't understand how (or why) you think of it as a one-to-one relationship. Or maybe you mean another new relationship?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67210/discussion-between-ammar-khan-and-haim770).

Comment: Sorry, I can't make it work.

Answer (score 6):

You can't have a relationship between two entities that is defined differently from either end. So you can't do 1:* from one direction and 1:1 from another.

Let me make a guess that you don't really want it to be 1:1 from the dependent end. From that end it will always only point to one thing.

In mappings, unlike in life, unless you have many to many, a child only has one parent.

You can, however, create a 0..1 : * relationaship (zero or one to many). Where the parent can have one or more children (e.g. "many") but the child can exist without a parent, but it can never have more than one parent (e.g. "zero or one").

Here is the simplest method of making your classes result in a [zero or one] to many relationship. Notice that I made the foreign key in the class Y a nullable int. WIth this setup, EF conventions will result in a mapping that lets a child exist without a parent.

```
public class X
  {
    [Key]
    public int XId { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Y> Y { get; set; }

  }

  public class Y
  {
    [Key]
    public int YId { get; set; }
    public int? XId { get; set; }
    public X X { get; set; }
  }

  public class DataContext : DbContext
  {
    public DbSet<X> XSet { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Y> YSet { get; set; }
   }
```

Here is a screenshot of visual model derived from the above classes and context.
I think this achieves the behavior you are seeking if my guess that you may just be perceiving it differently is correct.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your time and suggestion. Actually my scenario is little bit different, What will happen with 1:* relationship, X should have it's parent Y.  The reason why I wanted to create 1:1 relationship (which is not possible as you said) is, there will be a field in X entity, which will decide weather there is a need to be a relative record in Y.Let me give you a brief overview with the real entities I have...

Comment: In my application there will be a Super User (Y) who can have many Singles (X) record. If a Single (X) record has an Email field defined then there is a need to create a corresponding Client User Account (Y) by using that email field. If the email field does not exist in Single (X), then there will be no need for corresponding Client User Account (Y). So, it's suppose to be optional.. The Client User (Y) will only have concern to it's relative Single (X) record.. Do you think it is somehow achievable?

Answer (score 3):

Using the actual class names you mentioned in the comments:

Mapping a `User` that can have many `Single`s is not a problem. However, when you want to map a 1:1 association between a `User` and a `Single` you have to choose which of the two is the "principle" entity. You can't have a foreign key column in both tables because one entity will always be inserted before the other one. The "dependent" entity is inserted next, and it refers to the principal's primary key value.

So if `User` is the principal entity, you could have a class model similar to this:

```
public class User
{
    public User()
    {
        this.Singles = new HashSet<Single>();
    }

    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Single Single { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Single> Singles { get; set; }
}

public class Single
{
    public int SingleId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public int SuperUserId { get; set; }
    public User SuperUser { get; set; }
}
```

And two options for mappings:

#### Option 1: `User` as principal

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasMany(u => u.Singles)
        .WithRequired(s => s.SuperUser).HasForeignKey(s => s.SuperUserId);
    modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasOptional(s => s.Single)
        .WithOptionalPrincipal(s => s.User).Map(m => m.MapKey("UserId"));
}
```

In the data model, `Single` now has two foreign keys, `UserId` and `SuperUserId`. This is how to create a `User` and a `Single` in `User.Single` *and* `User.Singles`:

```
var superUser = new User { Name = "superUser1" };
var single = new Single { Name = "single" };
superUser.Singles.Add(single);
db.Users.Add(superUser);
superUser.Single = single;
db.SaveChanges();
```

And EF will first insert the `User`, then the `Single` having both foreign keys equal to the `User`'s primary key.

#### Option 2: `Single` as principle

You can also make `Single` the principal entity in the 1:1 association:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasOptional(s => s.Single)
    .WithOptionalDependent(s => s.User).Map(m => m.MapKey("SingleId"));
```

Now there's only one foreign key in `Single` (`SuperUserId`) and a foreign key in `User` (`SingleId`). If you execute the same code, now EF will throw

> Unable to determine a valid ordering for dependent operations.

This is because there is a chicken-and-egg problem: the `Single` must be created before the dependent `User` can be created, but the `User` must be created before the `Single` can be added to its `Singles` collection. This *could* be solved by assigning the `Single` later:

```
var superUser = new User { Name = "superUser1" };
var single = new Single { Name = "single" };
superUser.Singles.Add(single);
db.Users.Add(superUser);
db.SaveChanges();

superUser.Single = single;
db.SaveChanges();
```

You'd want to wrap this in a `TransactionScope`, so I think this option is less viable.

**Note**
As you see, in a 1:1 mapping the foreign key can't be mapped to a property in the class model. There is no `HasForeignKey` in the fluent API after `WithOptionalDependent` or `WithOptionalPrincipal`. Also, this association can only be mapped by the fluent API. In data annotations there is not attribute to indicate the principal end of an association.

Comment: Thanks for your detail answer. I would be interested in knowing these two things.

1) How would I assign the value to the `MapKey (SingleId)` in this case?

2) Let say, Super User have two Singles record. In `User` table, it only have the `SingleId`for 2nd record. So, If I delete the Super User from database, will this delete all the related data include (that Super Single and it's related optional user)?

Comment: I added some further explanation.